# Why can I edit a post without peer review, but when peer reviewing it's not enough that I approve it?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I have 2000+ reputation on arqade, this means that [my edits are applied without going through peer review and I can review suggested edits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). However, when I review edits in the review queue, then it requires an additional vote to approve the edit.

It would have been possible for me to make an edit exactly like the suggested one on my own, in which case there would be no second opinion required.

I don't suggest that we change this system, but why is there a difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Robo-reviewers click the approve button continuously and I'm afraid we need to protect against that. Some people just want a badge no matter what the consequences.

Eventually audit failures stop them if they're on a site with review audits, but we don't really want to have to undo all the damage they would cause if we just let a single button press be enough to change things, and as Catija said, there are no audits on most sites.

Comment: This actually makes sense, though I'd expect 2000+ reputation users to use the review queue responsibly. This is one of those things where I just have to think "why didn't I think of this?" after reading the answer.

Comment: There's no audits on most sites.

Comment: I think it's also that, if you're editing a post, you're probably paying attention. Even if you are a serious reviewer, you could miss a problem with a suggested edit.

Answer (score 8):

If, for whatever reason, it is so important for you to be able to approve a suggested edit immediately, there is a simple enough workaround. Instead of selecting "approve" in the review queue you can select "improve edit":

[image: Screenshot showing the "improve edit" option]

Using this option causes the edit to be applied immediately, even though no one else has approved it. So it's not that you lose the ability to instantly determine whether an edit is good or bad; you just have to do it a certain way if you want to use that ability.

Comment: Technically (IIRC) you can even override a pending edit, without reviewing it (or after doing so), by going to `/postID/edit`. This will cause the pending edit to get rejected with the reason "conflicted with a later edit", though.

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question, it is related and informative though, and it may be useful for some, so I won't downvote it.

Comment: And in case the edit is of such poor quality, or maybe actually harmful, Reject and Edit will do a similar thing. If a suggested edit is really problematically, you might also want to consider raising a custom flag on the post, indicating that suggested edit by user XXXX is a real problem because of YYYY. In case a user makes more of these problematic errors steps might be taken by moderators.